# Json schema django rest framework, describe json field as json and not as string

Tags: django-rest-framework, jsonschema, django-rest-swagger

I have an Api in DRF, describes with swagger.
In my serializer i have a field like that :

```
settings = serializers.DictField(child=serializers.JSONField())
```

Is it possible that in the swagger.json the field was describe as 'Json' and not as string:

```
"additionalProperties": {
            "type": "string"
}
```

but

```
"additionalProperties": {
        "type": "JSON"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry this is not possbile with JSON Schema.

The types are the primitive types allowed by JSON.

Comment: Do you now if it's possible to define a custom serializer Field with a custom type ? So I will be able to create a custom JsonField.

Comment: I need my auto-generated input in my form to be a textarea and not just a text input (which is the input associated with String)...

Comment: JSON Schema was designed for validating JSON data. If your field is a string encoded JSON (in your JSON), then you could use a regex (`pattern` keyword) to validate that the string is valid JSON. It would be helpful if you could include example JSON data you want to validate.